# Session is not destroying though called session_destroy()

Tags: php, session-variables

I am developing system with sessions in which I have put the code to start session after successful login and assigned values to session variables like `$_SESSION['email']`. Also, I have put a session destroy code, but the session doesn't seem to destroy. I have following files - **index.php**
This file grants the access to user for correct credentials with following code:

```
if(password_verify($password,$dbpass)){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, image FROM admins WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($name,$image);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['image'] = $image;
    header("Location:insert.php");
}
```

It works fine by setting session variables and redirects to intended file. In the file `insert.php`, I have imported file `session.php` which has below code:

```php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

also, I have a logout.php file which has following code:

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    session_destroy();
}
header("Location: index.php");
```

After running `logout.php`, if i again tries to access file `insert.php`, it opens, though the session file is imported in it. It should be redirected to `index.php` file. What is going wrong? Anyone please help.

Comment: Did you check all session data is displayed after again redirect

Comment: @RobinSingh yes, all data is also present after redirect

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in your log out file as well?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson as shown in above code, I don't have `session_start()` in logout.php

Comment: You need to. If you don't, you haven't started the session you want to destroy.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If I added that, the user is redirected to index file though successful login

Comment: _Side note:_ When doing `header('location: ...')`, always put an `exit;` after it to make sure no code after it get's executed.

Comment: If you include your file `session.php`, then yes. But you should only add `session_start();` in the top of `logout.php`. You need to have it there, or you won't be using the session you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your session and your $_SESSION server variables are seperate.
The session will be broken but the variable won't be empty.

Try this:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();

//Now you can choose whether you want to unset all sessions, or specific one(s):
$unset_sessions = ['email'];

foreach($_SESSION as $session => $session_value) {
   if (in_array($session, $unset_sessions))
      unset($_SESSION[$session]);
}

//Or all of them:
$_SESSION = [];
```

Thought it'd be fun to also create a function out of this:

````
function breakSessions($specifics= []) {

   if (!empty($specific)) { //Handle specifics
      foreach($_SESSION as $session => $session_value) {
         if (in_array($session, $specifics))
            unset($_SESSION[$session]);
      }
   } else {
      $_SESSION = [];
   }

}

breakSessions(['login', 'remember_me']) //Specifics;
breakSessions(); //All of them```
````

Comment: just use $_SESSION=null; to destroy entire array

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But will u please explain what you corrected and above logic?

Comment: The physical session you are talking about is a server global variable called $_SESSION which stores all of the actual sessions. After you break all the actual sessions, the data will still be in $_SESSION and what i did was simply unset that. - Please pick my answer as the correct one so it may help others :)

Comment: The thing that made this work is most likely the `session_start()` which your original `logout.php` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
}
header("Location: index.php");
```

You can't destroy a session without having "start" before. It's reccomended to have a session file which contains "session_start();" which you build templates from so that every page always have "session_start();"